# how to install the script interactive via ansible playbook

Tags: shell, ansible

I can run the script with the command line argument on the linux server it works fine.

for e.g.: `./install.sh -n -I <IP address of the server>`

The above command is able to install the script on the server.

When I am trying to do via ansible (version 2.5) playbook using the shell module it gives me an argument error.

```
  - name: Running the script
     shell: yes | ./fullinstall
```

Expect modules has been tried.

```
--my-arg1=IP address
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- shell: "./install.sh -n -I"
  args: 
    chdir: somedir/
    creates: somelog.txt
```

You can look [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html) for examples.

You can also place the *install.sh* file on the server as a template. Then you can set the variables as desired in Jinja2.

```
- name: Template install.sh
  template:
    src: /install.sh.j2
    dest: /tmp/install.sh

- shell: "cd /tmp/ ; ./install.sh
```

Your install.sh.j2 contains:

```
IP adres: {{ my_ip }}
```

And set the variable on the command line with:

```
ansible-playbook -e my_ip="192.168.0.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Use command module

```
- name: run script 
  command: /path/to/install.sh -n -I {{ ip_addrress }}
```

#### playbook

```
ansible-playbook -e ip_address="192.168.3.9" play.yml
```

If you want to interactively wanted to enter the IP address,  use `prompt` module.